# How to set a image in QLabel, QT?

Tags: qt, qlabel

want to set image in QLabels for a little game in QT:
I'm a beginner in QT.

My Header is:

```
#include <QWidget>
#include <QPushButton>
class Window : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

 public:
 explicit Window(QWidget *parent = 0);
 void initButtons();
 void initMap();

signals:
public slots:

private:
    QPushButton *m_button;
    QLabel *label;


};
```

in .cpp

```
Window::Window(QWidget *parent) : QWidget (parent)
{
    setFixedSize(1500,900);

    m_button = new QPushButton("Hello world", this);
    m_button->setGeometry(10,10,80,30);
    label = new QLabel("I'm a label", this);
    label->setGeometry(50,50,80,30);
    // ? hot to set image in label
}
```

Can you help me, please?

I've look the post with a pixmap and other layouts but i did't can to set the image in the labels..

Comment: Use [`QPixmap::fromImage`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpixmap.html#fromImage) to convert the image to a pixmap and follow the pixmap tutorial

Comment: @Felix image is different to QImage

Comment: [setPixmap](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlabel.html#pixmap-prop) is the correct one, but then again - it is a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define a resource in project.qrc file like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE RCC><RCC version="1.0">
<qresource prefix="/">
   <file>resources/icon.svg</file>
</qresource>                                                                     
</RCC>
```

And add a resource in your .pro file:

```
RESOURCES += project.qrc
```

And then in code you can simply do:

```
label->setPixmap(QPixmap(":/resources/icon.svg"));
```

Assuming you already have .pro and .qrc files somewhere in your project, you can just edit those.

Comment: icon.svg is in folder "resources" in this example

Comment: The OP asks about QLabels, not QPushButtons.

Comment: @scopchanov missed that one, fixed.